# Wrong subject name of SA for prometheus clusterrolebinding?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Since sa name is "prometheus" in file prometheus-serviceaccount.yaml,

```
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    app: prometheus
  namespace: default
```

do you think subject name in file prometheus-clusterrolebinding.yaml should be "prometheus" rather than current "default"?

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    app: prometheus
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

There are the similar problems for prometheus-proxy.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reporting this. Could you create an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues ? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I submitted an issue: [3618](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3618). Thank you.